# jQuery UI dialog is not draggable or resizable

Tags: jquery-ui

I am having issues getting a dialog to be draggable and resizable.  All the documentation and questions on this make it sound straightforword, but I cannot get it to work.  Any idea what I may doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></SCRIPT>
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#dialog-form').dialog({
//  autoOpen: false,
  height: 400,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  draggable: true,
  resizable: true,
  buttons: {
   Cancel: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
   }
  },
  close: function() {
   alert('here');
  }
 });
});
    </SCRIPT>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <style>
#dialog-form label {float:left; width:100px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new product">
    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="pt">Product Type</label>
        <input type="text" name="pt" id="pt" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  <br>
        <label for="prod">Producer</label>
        <input type="text" name="prod" id="prod" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because the draggable script is not self-containing.
You also need to include a mouse event handling library.

```
<script src="...../ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
```

additionally to

```
<script src="...../ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
```

**Performance-Note:** dropping and dragging functionality adds roughly 45kb (uncompressed) of additional javascript. This is almost as much code as is required to get basic UI functionality out of jquery-ui.

Comment: It should be noted that "draggable" and "resizable" are *not* automatically selected when selecting "dialog". This was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Has to be something in your code that is wrong... are you effectily loading everything and in the right order?

your code in [**JsBin**](http://jsbin.com) > http://jsbin.com/uqahu3/edit

works out of the box.

Comment: This is likely the problem - I had the same issue and it turned out that my custom jqueryui javascript didn't include the ui.mouse.js which is required.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using IE 6 and are having an issue.  If you are using IE 6 try including bgiframe.js http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe

Comment: I wish there was an easy way to make people get rid of IE6

Comment: I stumbled across this while searching for related info and thought I'd to @Avitus' comment... it is that easy.  My company does not support IE.  No Chrome, no Safari... nothing except Firefox.  Period.  Doesn't matter if the support need is for a company or non-company site.  Can't change the world if you don't change yourself.  Employees are free to choose their browser but they know if they have difficulties they won't get help for non-Firefox issues.  The sites we build are only tested with Firefox.  And traffic coming from the Internet to our sites get a message about this.